# Editing certain space in a line using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hello I have the txt file list:

```
asjd
gsgs
azda
```

I want to edit the 2nd spot on the line so it is such:

```
a-jd
g-gs
a-da
```

I have tried playing around with the \S reg expression but I am struggling. This is out of my knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: note the txt file is 200000 lines. I want to put a - on the second spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^(.).(.*)$
Replace: $1-$2
```

### Demo

Comment: Tim you are the best. You never miss.